# Telling a module to be imported first by the module itself?

Tags: python, import, module

I've added support for mods for my game. Any Python module put in a specific folder is automatically imported on startup. All is fine, except now I've written an official mod which allows mod makers to easily add GUI settings of their mods to a single toggable GUI frame. They are not forced to use it, but it greatly simplifies adding GUI settings with helper functions and makes things more organized and simpler for the players.

The problem is since its a mod itself, its imported on startup with the rest of the mods (Python modules), so if there is another mod which has a name which comes before it, it cannot use my mod. I know I could add "0_" or something to my module's name, but that wouldn't be very clean and you can't be very sure someone won't name his own mod's modules like that.

So I'm wondering if there's any way to tell Python to import a module first, by specifying it inside the module itself? I'm pretty sure there isn't, but who knows?

One solution I thought of is to make a subfolder which would be searched for modules first.

Another one might be merging the mod's code with the game's. Don't want to do that as to not give the impression that it's the only way to add mod settings.

Comment: How do the other mods access your offical mod? By `import`?

Comment: That, or making my mod's class instance a __builtin__ (which, I know, isn't the best idea).

Comment: The import statement already causes the imported module to be executed before the execution of the importing module continues. Maybe you don't have a problem at all?

Comment: *scratches head and feels like an idiot* I should just tell mod makers to import other mods they depend on...

Comment: I don't really know a good solution to this, but nothing of it seems to be particularilly clean. How about doing some research how other tools handle plugins, e.g., Sphinx or Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not have a list of all "system" modules that you need to have loaded which will be imported first, before then looking in sub-folders for all your mods and importing those ?

That way you still maintain your base system and only afterwards do you load up subsequent user mods.

Comment: You mean have some official module names hardcoded into the game and searched first? Hm, the problem is what if someone else makes a mod like that which should be imported and made available first? But seems like a fine idea for this at least. Thanks.

Comment: Like a complete conversion mod ? If that were the case, surely the initial "loader" which starts your base system would point to their base initialiser instead ?

Comment: I just mean a mod which is meant to be used by other mods (so must be imported before them).

Comment: Whatever, found out there is no problem at all... (read the replies to my post)